# "Fatal error in launcher:" when using pip or flask

Tags: python

When I try to install anything with Pip, it gives me the "Fatal error in launcher:" error. That wouldn't be too bad, since I know how to update Pip differently. However, the same error occurs when I try to run the "flask run" command.

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.8.2 and I have previously set the FLASK_APP variable to flaskblog.py. This is its content:

```
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route("/")
 def hello():
     return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Set Debug=True and post what return when you try to start your flask app. Also send more details. what OS you're using? Python version and etc.

Comment: It would be good to post the complete stacktrace of the error so that everyone unserstands it clearly.

Comment: It would be even better if I knew what it is, and how to find it. I executed the command in cmd, there's no more output than that.

Comment: have you tried the install using `python -m pip install <pkg-name>` ?

Comment: Yes, and it works. But the flask command still doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted the error clearly, if `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ‘”‘` is your error,

then you might want to update `pip` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and try installing your package again using `python -m pip install <pkg-name>`. You should get it working.

if the error persists after the above mentioned steps, the try importing `pip` in your python console(pull up your terminal and type `python` then type `import pip`) and try `pip.main([‘install’,’<pkg-name>’])` in the console.

Hope this helps.

referred from [here](http://www.sysrecon.com/programming/python-pip-how-to-get-around-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using/)

#### Edit

Alternatively, you can run your flask app by adding `app.run()` in your script.

Like:

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    app.run()
```

and then in the terminal, run `python -m flaskblog.py`.

Note: if you want to run your app in debug mode, consder giving `debug = True` to `app.run()`.

Comment: Well, the thing is I only get "Fatal error in launcher:". There's nothing after the colon.

Comment: so, the above steps didn't help?

Comment: Well, they kinda did. I managed to both update pip and install flask, but I still get the error when executing the "flask run" command.

Comment: or you should consider running your flask app by adding `app.run()` in your script. Like this `if __name__ == __main__: app.run()` . Then in the terminal, run `python -m flaskblog.py`

Comment: Oh wow, this acutally worked! Thanks a lot dude. I just wish there was a way to use the standard command.

Comment: @Miloszun If it helped, consider accepting the answer so that others can find the answer easily. Cheers!